# All sticky posts are returned in custom query

Tags: wp-query, sticky-post

I have the following code:

```
$recommended_args = 
    array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'post__in' => get_option('sticky_posts'),
            'orderby' => 'date'
        );

$recommended_query = new WP_Query($recommended_args);
if ($recommended_query->have_posts()) {
    while($recommended_query->have_posts()) {
        $recommended_query->the_post();
        get_template_part("templates/article-random");
    }
}
```

Basically, it should return the 3 most recent posts marked as sticky. However, it dumps all (more than 3) sticky posts in the DB onto the screen.

What is wrong with the arguments? Is there a way to fix this without having to replace the `while` loop with a `for` loop that iterates only over the first 3 in the `WP_Query` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is default behavior when the `post__in` parameter is used. If you read the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters), you will see that you should set `'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1` to eliminate sticky posts being queried

### EDIT

Your query arguments should look like this

```
$recommended_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post__in' => get_option('sticky_posts'),
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);
```

### EDIT 2

By default, `WP_Query` (no matter if this is the main query or a custom query) searches and returns all sticky posts at the top of the first page. All other query parameters are ignored, specially `posts_per_page`. If you have 100 stickies, and `posts_per_page` is set to `3`, all 100 sticky posts will be returned regardless with 3 posts that is not in the sticky posts array

These sticky posts is then removed from its original place in the query to avoid duplicates. When you pass `get_option( 'sticky_posts' )` to `post__in`, these sticky posts are simply removed from the query as `WP_Query` has already returned them as sticky posts, this is to avoid them being shown as duplicates.

To make your query work, you **have to** "switch" off the sticky posts feature so that `WP_Query` can exclude them and just focus on the query at hand. For this you will need to set the `ignore_sticky_posts` paramter to `1` which means that sticky posts will be ignored

I hope this makes sense now

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want to get all posts that satisfy my custom query INCLUDING the sticky posts in that set. So not all sticky posts in the system..?

Comment: Also do we still need to specify the `'post__in' => get_option('sticky_posts'),` if we're saying ignore sticky posts?