# Query sticky posts with thumbnails

Tags: wp-query, loop, post-thumbnails, meta-query, sticky-post

I need to display max 5 latest sticky posts that have a thumbnail. And I need to have accurate counting of the displayed posts. I've tried to exclude sticky posts without a thumbnail with meta_query, but with no luck.

```
$sticky = get_option('sticky_posts');

if (empty($sticky)) {
    return;
}

$counter = 1;

$r = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post__in'       =>  $sticky,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_thumbnail_id',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'orderby'        => 'post__in',
    'post_type'      => array( 'post' ),
));


if ($r->have_posts()) :

    echo '<section class="header-sticky-posts '.$post_count.'">';

        while ( $r->have_posts() ) : $r->the_post();

            echo '<div class="header-sticky-post">';
                // Post content
            echo '</div>';

        $counter++; 
        endwhile;

    echo '</section>';

endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `ignore_sticky_posts` to `true` in your query arguments. This way you exclude sticky posts and only focus on the post ID's array being passed to `post_in`

```
'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
```

### EDIT

If this does not make much sense, please see [my answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/192253/31545) to similar question where I have explained it a bit better. Be sure to check it out

### THE CODE

```
$r = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post__in'       =>  $sticky,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_thumbnail_id',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'orderby'        => 'post__in',
    'post_type'      => array( 'post' ),
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
));
```

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked. Enjoy :-)

Comment: Do you know if there is any difference if I use 'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id' instead of meta_query? Both seem to work.

Comment: There is no difference. Both syntaxes are correct and will work. The only real difference is in that with a `meta_query` you can build nested and more complex queries which you can't do with the `meta_*` syntax :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is right except that you are careless or you just copied code from somewhere else and pasted in without modifying it.

```
<?php
$sticky = get_option('sticky_posts');

if (empty($sticky)) {
    return;
}

$counter = 1;

$posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post__in'       =>  $sticky,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_thumbnail_id',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'orderby'        => 'post__in',
    'post_type'      => array( 'post' ),
));


if ($posts->have_posts()) :

        while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();

                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
                    echo '<section class="header-sticky-posts'.$counter.'">';
                    echo '<div class="header-sticky-post">';
                            the_post_thumbnail();
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '</section>';
                    $counter++; 
                endif;

        endwhile;

endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: This is my code. You could be more specific with your answer. I see that you propose to check if there is a thumbnail in the loop. But it's not what I was looking for. Yes, sticky posts without thumb will not be displayed. But they will still be counted in the query.

Comment: you use $r->have_post() that is wrong. and also you put a slash before WP_Query which should not be there. You want to display five sticky post, and the code perfectly displays the 5 sticky posts. So what is it you want ?

Comment: Why is $r wrong? :) There is a slash before WP_Query because I use PHP namespaces in my project, and I just forgot to delete it when posted here. It has nothing to do with the question. 
Firstly, I want to display 5 sticky posts only with thumbnails. So if we have 5 sticky posts in total, and 4 of them are with thumbnails, this code must output this 4 posts only. Your solution works here. 
Secondly, I need to keep post counting accurate. So if the post is not displayed, it must not be counted. Your solution fails here.
Your remarks are not related to the question, sorry.

Comment: You set $posts as query variable and you are using $r for execution it does not make sense to me. To your second question put the counter variable inside the if condition
 if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : 
 echo '<div class="header-sticky-post">';
 the_post_thumbnail();
 echo '</div>';
 $counter++;
 endif;

Comment: It was just a typo, sorry. Your suggestion to put $counter++ inside "if statement" doesn't seem to do the job.

Comment: How about the edit that I have just made? If that doesn't work I'm sorry.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: sorry my answer isn't correct solution to the question.